# kinect issues on different machines

Tags: ros, kinect, messages, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I tried running the following launch script, with my kinect, on two different machines, on the first one (desktop) everything works fine, on the second one (laptop) nothing works:

```
<launch>
  <!-- kinect and frame ids -->
  <include file="$(find openni_camera)/launch/openni_node.launch"/>

  <!-- openni manager -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="openni_manager" output="screen" respawn="true" args="manager"/>

  <!-- throttling -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="pointcloud_throttle" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle openni_manager">
    <param name="max_rate" value="2"/>
    <remap from="cloud_in" to="/camera/depth/points"/>
    <remap from="cloud_out" to="cloud_throttled"/>
  </node>

  <!-- fake laser -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="kinect_laser" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager">
    <param name="output_frame_id" value="/openni_depth_frame"/>
    <remap from="cloud" to="cloud_throttled"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

on the laptop the output looks exaclty the same like on the desktop:

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /openni_node1/use_indices
 * /openni_node1/depth_registration
 * /openni_node1/image_time_offset
 * /openni_node1/depth_frame_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_mode
 * /kinect_laser/output_frame_id
 * /openni_node1/debayering
 * /rosversion
 * /openni_node1/projector_depth_baseline
 * /openni_node1/rgb_frame_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_rgb_translation
 * /pointcloud_throttle/max_rate
 * /openni_node1/depth_time_offset
 * /openni_node1/image_mode
 * /openni_node1/shift_offset
 * /openni_node1/device_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_rgb_rotation

NODES
  /
    openni_node1 (openni_camera/openni_node)
    kinect_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    openni_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    pointcloud_throttle (nodelet/nodelet)
    kinect_laser (nodelet/nodelet)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [4969]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 34911bc8-53e3-11e1-96ac-0023dfffccb1
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [4982]
started core service [/rosout]
process[openni_node1-2]: started with pid [4985]
process[kinect_base_link-3]: started with pid [4986]
process[kinect_base_link1-4]: started with pid [4987]
process[kinect_base_link2-5]: started with pid [4988]
process[kinect_base_link3-6]: started with pid [4989]
process[openni_manager-7]: started with pid [4990]
process[pointcloud_throttle-8]: started with pid [4991]
process[kinect_laser-9]: started with pid [4992]
[ INFO] [1328877118.394903193]: [/openni_node1] Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1328877118.395245674]: [/openni_node1] 1. device on bus 002:30 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00363A03948136A'
[ INFO] [1328877118.398388308]: [/openni_node1] searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1328877118.446196137]: [/openni_node1] Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 2:30 with serial number 'A00363A03948136A'
[ INFO] [1328877118.454999825]: rgb_frame_id = '/openni_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1328877118.456160538]: depth_frame_id = '/openni_depth_optical_frame'
```

no errors, nothing.

The problem is that on the laptop there is nothing going one on the topics. e.g. listening to /camera/depth/points or /scan on the desktop I can see messages comming in, on the laptop there is nothing, silence.

There is a difference in the dmesg output. On the desktop:

```
usb 2-1.4: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 35
usb 2-1.4: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
hub 2-1.4:1.0: USB hub found
hub 2-1.4:1.0: 3 ports detected
usb 2-1.4.2: new full speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 36
usb 2-1.4.2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
usb 2-1.4.1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 37
usb 2-1.4.1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
usb 2-1.4.3: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 38
usb 2-1.4.3: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
```

On the laptop:

```
usb 1-5: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 33
hub 1-5:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-5:1.0: 3 ports detected
usb 1-5.2: new full speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 34
usb 1-5.1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 35
usb 1-5.3: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 36
composite sync not supported
```

Any idea what the problem might be? roswtf is not showing me any errors...

**update**

I tried running kinect with libfreenect and this is the output from the freenect-glview demo (I can see both depth and camera image):

```
[Stream 80] Inconsistent flag 82 with 161 packets in buf (162 total), resyncing...
[Stream 80] Invalid magic fefe
[Stream 80] Lost 1 packets
[Stream 80] Lost 4 packets
[Stream 80] Inconsistent flag 82 with 161 packets in buf (162 total), resyncing...
[Stream 70] Invalid magic b6b6
[Stream 70] Invalid magic 6ba9
[Stream 70] Lost 6 packets
[Stream 70] Lost too many packets, resyncing...
[Stream 80] Invalid magic fefe
[Stream 80] Lost 1 packets
[Stream 80] Lost 4 packets
[Stream 80] Inconsistent flag 82 with 161 packets in buf (162 total), resyncing...
[Stream 70] Invalid magic a4ff
[Stream 70] Invalid magic 2b65
[Stream 70] Lost 7 packets
[Stream 70] Lost too many packets, resyncing...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12973/kinect-issues-on-different-machines/) by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 345 on 2012-02-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2012-02-10**:
What laptop is it, and what USB port? I've had a problem with the kinect on USB 3 ports on a newer Dell laptop, but I don't remember if the symptoms were the same as you describe

**Comment by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) on 2012-02-13**:
USB 2.0 on Asus Eee PC 1005HA. btw. I've added freenect-glview output to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer my own question, my Eee PC is  too slow and dropping too many packets. htop is showing CPU usage >97%. That's the reason why ROS is not working at all and libfreenect says "Lost too many packets". I've tried it with a "normal" Laptop and everything works fine. Mystery solved.

---

Originally posted by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) with karma: 345 on 2012-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0